# What determines the placement of weiter?

Tags: word-order

I have had the impression that adverbs stay close to the verb in German word order. So why is this incorrect (as I was told):

> Der Traktor rollte **weiter** 10 Fuß.

and this is instead correct?

> Der Traktor rollte 10 Fuß **weiter**.

I note, for instance, that in DWDS both "weiter zu Fuß" and "zu Fuß weiter" occur, albeit with the latter being more frequent.

As a related example of the use of a verb with an adverb instead the associated compound verb is [this sentence](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=NEAR%28%20nehmen%2C%20mit%2C%205%29&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=10) from DWDS which uses nehmen with mit instead of mitnehmen:

> Doch Roggenkamp hatte ihn mal wieder beiseite geschoben und diesen violetten Manipel, den er übrigens **mit** heim **nahm**, aus der Tasche gezogen.

Comment: Your last sentence isn't very useful, because the DWDS examples don't mean what you seem to think.

Comment: Maybe also read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Awful_German_Language cited in https://www.destination-munich.com/mark-twains-essay-on-german.html.

Comment: Nitpicking: In Europe we use the metric system. Wo don't say *»Der Traktor rollte 10 Fuß weiter.«* We say *»Der Traktor rollte 3 Meter weiter.«*

Comment: The sentences "Wir gehen weiter zu Fuß" and "Wir gehen zu Fuß weiter" are both grammatically correct, but their pragmatic meaning is very different. In some contexts, one might mean almost the opposite of the other. Mark Twain would love this. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The placement is determined by function.
I'll modify the examples a little to illustrate the points better.

1. a prefix

- Der Zug fährt gleich weiter. (weiterfahren)

In this case it'll come "at the end" (all exceptions apply)

2. a comparative

- Ich werfe 10 Meter weiter (als Maria).

In this case, it'll come after the unit count.

3. an adverb of "mode"

- Ich komme weiter zu spät zur Arbeit.

In this case, it'll come before what it talks about.

The example in question could be a prefix or a comparative. I am actually reading it more as a comparative than a prefix, but I can't think of a good linguistic test to tell.

Comment: Although this is the best explanation so far, it is, unfortunately not verifiable by usage. These sentences are taken from DWDS:  Als der Wagen streikte, mußte sie zu Fuß weiter.   Der 19jährige war weiter zu Fuß geflüchtet und eingeholt worden.

Comment: Not sure, how that doesn't fit with my explanation. The examples you gave are case 1 and 3, respectively.

Comment: Ok. Then let me provide an example that cannot possible be consistent with case 1 because there is no associated compound verb in Duden:  Beamte verfolgten ihn solange bis er die Kontrolle über seinen Wagen verlor und zu Fuß weiter flüchtete. DWDS: https://bit.ly/3PIkZnN. This cannot be comparative and is not a prefix. It must be an adverb of mode, but it follows zu Fuß.

Comment: Late but better now than never. Just because Duden doesn't list something, that doesn't mean it doesn't exist. https://taz.de/!1447204/ What you'd need to know to take Duden as a reference is to check if, ACCORDING to Duden, the sentence is grammatically correct and the "weiter" can be behind "zu Fuß" but not attached to "flüchten". Besides, if it is an adverb of mode, then it's like "zu Fuß", which is also an adverbial of mode. I don#t think there are rules as to how to order those. "weiter zu Fuß, zu Fuß weiter" are the same thing then.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a simple rule that if you want to *qualify* an adverb in German, the qualifier goes in front of it:

1. Der Traktor rollte noch 5 Meter weiter
2. Der Traktor rollte noch sehr viel weiter
3. Die Frau muss noch 2 Minuten länger warten
4. Der Athlet aus dem Kongo sprang 30cm höher als der aus Ghana

Then we need to distinguish between the adwerb ("how?") and the qualifier ("how in detail?"). Maybe it's better to use adverbs that are really interchangeable as examples, like in:

a. Er ging weiter links

b. Er ging links weiter

And a deliberately bumpy translation to highlight the difference:

a) says: "He walked - more to the left"

b) says "He walked more - to the left"

i.e. the "main" adverb is placed last, the qualifier qualifying that main adverb comes in front of it.

Comment: Well, that would be fine except both the weiter and the 10 Fuß are adverbs, each of which could be considered to qualify the other -- although the 10 Fuß actually quantifies, is that what makes the difference?

Comment: Well, again simple: "weiter" qualifies "10 Fuß". But not the other way round. Nothing to do with a measure. "weiter hinunter" would as well go this way.

Comment: I do not see why 10 Fuß cannot qualify weiter, just as well as weiter can qualify 10 Fuß. Unqualified weiter would not tell how much farther. 10 Fuß qualifies weiter to tell how much farther.

Answer (score 0):

Note that unlike "zu Fuß" which is a *Modal* Adverb, "weiter" is a *Local* Adverb - it doesn't describe *how* the tractor rolls, but *where to*.

- Der Traktor rollte noch 5 Meter **weiter**.
- Der Traktor rollte noch 5 Meter **nach links**.
- Der Traktor rollte noch 5 Meter **zurück**.

They should always be placed at the end of a sentence, and after the modal verb.

- Der Traktor rollte [laut knatternd] (modal) [die Straße hinunter] (local).

You can put the modal adverb at the beginning of the sentence and preserve the meaning...

- Laut knatternd rollte der Traktor die Straße hinunter

... but doing so with the local adverb along with its quantifier will sounds extremely unusual at best, and might totally change the meaning of the sentence at worst.

Comment: This statement is not consistent with the usage found for zu Fuß weiter/weiter zu Fuß. In addition, both 10 Fuß as well as weiter are local adverbs.

Comment: "zu Fuß weiter" describes how, not where to. They are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The verb is **weiterrollen**. [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/weiterrollen)

Weiterrollen is separable, so when it's finite the prefix **weiter** is placed at the end of the sentence.

Comment: This works for the specific example but doesn't answer OP's question in general; think *10 Meter weiter stand ein Traktor* or similar.

Comment: @DavidVogt: The question is  not very precise in that respect, when the only explicit example given is a different category.

Comment: On second thought, you're right, the question is unclear.

Comment: Why could the verb not be rollen with an adverb of weiter?

Comment: @user44591: when pressed, one probably  could interpret it that way,  but I am not convinced, whether many will share that view, and currently don't see an impact on the word order of the complete sentence.

Comment: The use of a language is subject to a range of interpretation, but that range is limited by a border beyond which more-or-less rigorous rules, generally recognized, take effect. The intention of this question was to place itself outside the border interpretation, to assess a more definitive cause for the word order. But so far, all I can say is that the word order is said to be customary, and violating the order is perceived as inarticulate, although without concrete linguistic basis.