# What is the meaning of ...treiben darauf zu?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading a story. It says

> Eine Libelle kommt angeflogen. Sie glänzt blau-grün.
> So etwas Schönes haben die Kleinen noch nie gesehen.
> Die Libelle fliegt weiter, und die Schwanenkinder schwimmen hinterher.
> Sie wissen nicht, dass dort hinten ein starker Strudel ist.
> Die kleinen Schwäne **treiben darauf zu**.

I don't understand the meaning of the bolded text. What is the meaning of "zu" there? Is "treiben darauf" a phrasal verb?

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zutreiben

Comment: @RHa: Bitte poste keine Antworten (auch keine halbfertigen Antwortfragmente) in den Kommentaren. Weitere vollwertige Antworten sind immer wollkommen. Siehe https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1658/1487 und https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/1487

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich mache das auf SO ständig, wenn die Fragen zu einfach sind. In den meisten Fällen findet sich auch jemand, der daraus eine ordentliche Antwort macht.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich kann nicht nachvollziehen, dass jeder Link auf einen Wörterbucheintrag als Antwortversuch oder -fragment gemeint sein muss, zumal bei (aktuell 2) Schließungswünschen die Deutung plausibel ist, dass sich der Fragende nach Lektüre des Eintrags über die Löschung der Frage Gedanken machen möge.

Comment: Link hinknallen ohne weiteren Text ist halt so passiv-aggressiv.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Der Link wurde nicht "hingeknallt", sondern einfach gepostet und aus der Tatsache der Veröffentlichung eine Gemütsverfassung ("passiv-aggressiv") ableiten zu wollen, ist schon reichlich fragwürdig. Über andere völlig beleglos verunglimpfende Behauptungen aufzustellen ist schon putzig, nachdem man das Posten eines Links als "passiv-aggressiv" apostrophiert hat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The verb is 'auf etwas / jmd. zutreiben' (to drift towards sth. /sb.). See also in [dwds](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/zutreiben) the 2nd meaning.

Here 'darauf' takes the place of the necessary Akkusativ object as back reference to the mentioned place in the previous sentence (der Strudel = the vortex).

'zutreiben' is a trennbares verb, so the normal sentence structure is

> Die Schwäne treiben auf den Strudel zu.
> (The swans drift towards the vortex)

And in order to not repeat the last sentence

> Dort ist ein Strudel. Die Schwäne treiben darauf zu. (there is a vortex. The swans drift towards it)

Comment: Sorry, but to complete the confusion of OP, I had an image in my head, where a bunch of swans drift towards a delicious strudel.

Comment: _'zutreiben' is a trennbares verb_ Nope.

Comment: @TaW what sort of argument is "nope"? The answer contains a link to a dictionary that lists that verb. If you disagree, you will have to explain.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree that this is a specific separable verb "zutreiben". The construction really involves the *circumposition* "auf X zu" (which is like a preposition, but goes on either side of the noun rather than just in front).

Similar constructions would be possible with pretty much every verb of movement: rollen, laufen, fliegen, stampfen etc. etc. It's not helpful to postulate a separate variant with "zu" for each of these verbs when the construction is completely regular and much easier to explain as a circumposition. (Also, how would you describe the complement of that verb - as an accusative object? That seems off.)

Confusion often arises because circumpositions, like prepositions, can fuse with pronouns, so that the following are equivalent:

- Die kleinen Schwäne treiben *auf den Strudel zu*.
- Die kleinen Schwäne treiben *auf ihn* [den Strudel] *zu*.
- Die kleinen Schwäne treiben *darauf zu*.

Comment: Intuitively, I agree with you. When I ask myself whether "wenn die Schwäne darauf zu treiben" or "wenn die Schwäne darauf zutreiben" is correct, my intuition leans towards the former, which would imply that the verb is "treiben", not "zutreiben". But after I looked up "zutreiben" in Duden and Wiktionary, I'm not sure anymore... https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zutreiben https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zutreiben

Comment: Das Problem gibt es hier öfters: Der Verweis auf ein (möglicherweise tatsächlich existierendes) trennbares Verb geht am Problem vorbei. Ich erinnere mich an https://german.stackexchange.com/a/71407/35111 und https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/59235/auf-den-sprechenden-zu.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answers glosses over the problem; referring to the dictionary or the existence of a separable verb obscures an important pattern.

Movement verbs can always be refined by combining them with an adverb.

> die Getränke **runter**bringen, **rauf**bringen, **rein**bringen, **raus**bringen, **her**bringen, **weg**bringen …

These can be combined with appropriate adverbial phrases.

> die Getränke runter **in den Keller** bringen
> etwas **aus dem Keller in die Wohnung** raufbringen
> den Hund **in die Wohnung** mit reinbringen

The word order *runter in den Keller bringen*, with *in den Keller* intraposed between the adverb and the verb, conflicts with a simple analysis as a separable verb *runterbringen*. Separable verbs do not allow this kind of split and only *in den Keller runterbringen* should be possible.

Sometimes, adverb and adverbial phrase must occur together.

> *Die Schwäne trieben weiter zu.
> *Die Schwäne trieben auf den Wasserfall.
> Die Schwäne trieben auf den Wasserfall zu.

Furthermore, only *auf den Wasserfall zu* can have the meaning "towards"; *auf* by itself would be *onto*.

Interestingly, the combination of adverbial phrase and adverb can also occur as an independent unit.

> Die Treppe **rauf in den ersten Stock** muss repariert werden.
> Da vorne links abbiegen und die Straße **raus aus der Stadt** nehmen.

Comment: "Die Schwäne trieben auf den Wasserfall" is ungrammatical as the location adverbial requires Dativ (as opposed to the direction which requires Akkusativ): "Die Schwäne trieben auf *dem* Wasserfall". E.g. mind the difference between "Ich gehe auf das Dach" (direction, not yet there) vs. "Ich gehe auf dem Dach" (location, already on it)

Comment: But *treiben* can combine with a direction: *die Schwäne trieben flussabwärts, zum Ufer*; so why is *trieben auf den Wasserfall* impossible?

Comment: I'd say yes, ungrammatical. "Treiben" requires use of the prepostion "zu" or the verb "zutreiben" with preoposition "auf" in order to take a direction (let's take See (=lake) as 'on a waterfall is a difficult concept): "Sie treiben zum See" or "Sie treiben auf den See zu" both mean they are drifting towards the lake. Drifting on the lake: "Sie treiben auf dem See"

Comment: Similarily the sentence "Die Schwäne trieben weiter zu" sounds awkward; it sounds to me like an uncomplete sentence - the direction is mission as 'zu' implies a direction; without a place drifting towards it has no place to be there and should be left out. If the place is mentioned before it needs a back reference like "... darauf zu".

Comment: And these facts are easily explained by treating *auf X zu* as a unit.

Comment: All this said, you might have a point that it's possibly pointless to specifically learn 'zutreiben' when you simply can memorize the  'zu einem Ort XXX' / 'auf einen Ort zuXXX' / 'auf einem Ort XXX' / 'von einem Ort weg/runter/hoch/weiter/...XXX' where XXX is an arbitrary verb of motion. Not sure how to call this concept. But still then these things like 'zutreiben', 'weggehen', 'runterholen' etc are effectively a separable verb or at least treated as such